# How to "copy" or transfer an NSManagedObject from a context in a private queue to another in the main queue?

Tags: ios, concurrency, copy, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm requesting data to web services and creating the corresponding `NSManagedObject` objects in a context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` concurrency type to avoid blocking the main thread. At the end of this process, I need to set the new information I've received to the `NSManagedObject` objects I have in a context in the main thread (the context that is created in `AppDelegate` by default).

Which is the correct/appropriate way to do this? I suppose this should be a common scenario, but I don't find any clear example... I've been thinking about some options:

A) To deep-clone somehow the objects in the private context to the main context.

B) To simply do something like this:

```
[mainContext deleteObject:<oldObjectInMainContext>];
[mainContext insertObject:<newObjectInPrivateContext>];
[mainContext save:nil];
```

But, since contexts are in different threads, I suppose this would cause problems...

Maybe the appropriate way isn't any of these. I'd appreciate some guidance to handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I create the private context this way:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

and I don't set it as child context of the main one.

Comment: How are the contexts created? Are they parent and child?

Comment: @Wain No, they aren`t... I've just edited my question.

Comment: Research parent and child contexts and how they work together

Comment: @Wain but child contexts have an impact on the main thread, don't they?

Comment: Parent/ child: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131

Comment: It sounds like you need a merge handler.  See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:).